# Set function that is non-negative, non-decreasing and finitely additive implies it is finitely subadditive

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\mu:2^\mathscr{X}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a non-decreasing, non-negative and finitely additive. Then is it always true that it must also be finitely sub-additive?

I am almost sure it is true...but I think I've been staring at it for too long and confusing myself now =(. Could some one please help and provide a proof?

Thanks

Comment: Subadditive is weaker than additive.

Comment: @Ian "Subadditive is weaker than additive" (for ***nonnegative*** set functions) is exactly what we are asked to prove here. It is easy enough to prove, but I don't see how an obvious restatement is helpful.

Comment: $f(S\cup T)=f(S)+f(T\setminus S)\le f(S)+f(T)$

Comment: I suppose I was assuming disjointness already, for which it is obvious even without the nonnegativity (it is just turning an equality sign into a nonstrict inequality sign). If finite subadditivity means that the finitely many sets don't have to be disjoint then there's actually something there to prove.

Comment: @Ian I suppose the OP is using [this definition of subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditive_set_function).

Comment: Thanks for the reply bof, I see I really was just overthinking it way too much now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B_1=A_1$ and $B_i=A_i\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{i-1})$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ then the sets $B_i$ are disjoint with $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n=B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_n$ so that:

$$\mu(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)=\mu(B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(B_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$$